# Regular expression to validate keyboard sequencing

Tags: javascript, regex, internationalization

How to form a regular expression that does not allow more than 3 characters in sequence from the keyboard for Korean?

I am able to do the same thing for English with:

```
var string = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm';
var limit = val.length - 2;
for(i=0;i<limit;i++){
  var substr = val.substr(i,3);
  var n = string.search(substr);
  if(n != -1)
    err++;
```

Where "val" is the password value. How can I implement the same for Korean?

- Valid case in English: `QRY`
- Valid case in English: `nfu`
- Invalid case in English: `qwete` (Because the first 3 chars are a US keyboard sequence).
- Invalid case in English: `ASDreq` (Because the first 3 chars are a US keyboard sequence).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to accept `한` and reject `한글` or `가자`?

Comment: I want to validate when a user enters any characters form the  keyboard in a sequence upto 3 provided on the Koraen keyboard,i need to throw a error.

Comment: Still it is not clear, please, provide samples for valid and invalid inputs.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov,

Valid Cases In English: QRY
Valid Cases In English: nfu

InValid Cases In English: qwete (Because 1st 3 chars are comes US keyboard sequence)
InValid Cases In English: ASDreq (Because 1st 3 chars are comes US keyboard sequence)

Comment: Why do you then mention Korean/Hangul?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, i need same validation for "Korean Keayboard" sequence.

Comment: @user3515080 : whys not just replace the korean sequence in `var string = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm';` ?

Comment: @user3515080 Do you mean that you don't want to accept `ㅂㅈㄷㄱ` or `화ㅣ`?

Comment: @NoobEditor, can you help on that ? (Replacing to korean sequence)

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, I also have same question. i think we don't need to have validation for Korean keyboard right ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are 4 different [Korean keyboard layouts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Hangul_.28for_Korean.29) which makes it really difficult to answer the question.

However, the solution for Korean keyboard layouts might be the same as for English keyboard layout. Just the string must be changed by replacing the English characters by the Korean characters.

As the Korean characters are Unicode characters, you need to use in the string the [Unicode escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings) `\uXXXX` for the Korean characters whereby `XXXX` is the hexadecimal value of the Korean character in Unicode table.